# External sound card Scarlett 2i2 not playing sound

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

I've got a first-generation Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 that I'd like to use as my sound card on 16.04. Following the instructions [here](http://dragly.org/2014/01/12/focusrite-scarlett-2i2-flawlessly-working-on-ubuntu-with-jack/), I installed PulseAudio JACK and the QjackCtl GUI. However, when I launch the GUI and check the connections, I can't see anything that resembles the 2i2:

[QjackCtl screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJzv0.png)

The 2i2 does show up when I run `aplay -l && arecord -l`:

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
      Subdevices: 0/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 2: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 3: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 4: USB [Scarlett 2i2 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC1150 Alt Analog [ALC1150 Alt Analog]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: U0x46d0x807 [USB Device 0x46d:0x807], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 4: USB [Scarlett 2i2 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And it also shows up when I run `lsusb`:

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
    Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:0807 Logitech, Inc. Webcam B500
    Bus 003 Device 009: ID 1235:8016 Focusrite-Novation 
    Bus 003 Device 007: ID 2687:fb01  
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have a Logitech Webcam and two GTX 660 GPUs, which explain some of the other devices listed, and I don't know if they're interfering with my ability to hook up the 2i2. I'm not sure where to go from here, as it seems the 2i2 is generally pretty plug-and-play. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In **qjackctl connections** , try to connect left side Pulseaudio jack sink to the last "system playback"   (right side) which is probably your 2i2 soundcard:
This can be be done by drag and drop from left item to desired right item,
or using "connect" or "disconnect" buttons after selecting items.